# Fatal Exception : Main android

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, program-entry-point

With my friends, we're working in a project and for it i need to create an android application. (I specify, I'm a beginner at programming in java).

So to start I've follow a good tutorial (http://www.buildcircuit.com/sensorgraph-using-android-amarino-and-arduino/)
it explain how to create a connection enter your arduino (microcontroller) and your arduino with amarino (bluetooth).

The program retrieves the value of the variable voltage and displays it on the phone.

But I've trouble, my program doesn't work. When i uploading it on my phone, it show a black window with an error message "Unfortunately, SensorGraph2 has stopped"
I don't know what I can do.

This the SensorGrpah.java:

```
package edu.mit.media.hlt.sensorgraph;
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino;
    import at.abraxas.amarino.AmarinoIntent;


public class SensorGraph extends Activity {


    private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS =  "00:15:FF:F2:0F:A8";

    private GraphView mGraph; 
    private TextView mValueTV;

    private ArduinoReceiver arduinoReceiver = new ArduinoReceiver();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mGraph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
        mValueTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);

        mGraph.setMaxValue(1024);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        registerReceiver(arduinoReceiver, new IntentFilter(AmarinoIntent.ACTION_RECEIVED));


        Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


        Amarino.disconnect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);


        unregisterReceiver(arduinoReceiver);
    }



    public class ArduinoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String data = null;


            final int dataType = intent.getIntExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA_TYPE, -1);


            if (dataType == AmarinoIntent.STRING_EXTRA){
                data = intent.getStringExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA);

                if (data != null){
                    mValueTV.setText(data);
                    try {

                        final int sensorReading = Integer.parseInt(data);
                        mGraph.addDataPoint(sensorReading);
                    } 
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) { /* oh data was not an integer */ }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <edu.mit.media.hlt.sensorgraph.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#fff"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the logCat when i'm trying to upload it on my phone

```
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at edu.mit.media.hlt.sensorgraph.SensorGraph.onStart(SensorGraph.java:71)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-14 00:30:56.640: E/AndroidRuntime(29568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Apparently the library that contains the class `at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino` does not get included correctly into the APK. Double check if the library is in the folder `libs`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common, I had the same trouble today. I solved it creating a folder libs in the project and adding the AmarinoLibrary's jar to this folder instead of add an external jar. After this all worked fine. Hope this help you:).